# I want to parse json to html, with angularjs, i am converting an xml to json with npm xml2json

Tags: json, angularjs, xml

I am using angularjs http to get an xml from the server, i am using node xml2json plugin to convert it to a json object. I get the document returned properly but it doesn't look right because i has html tags in the xml document. If anyone knows how to convert the returned json properly that would be great,

```
 var x2js = new X2JS();
 var dom = x2js.xml_str2json(chr);
<my_data> 
    <p class="justify">
        El 
        <strong>
             <em>
                  Content Tour 2015
             </em>
        </strong> 
        <strong>
            Distributors 
        </strong>
    </p>
</my_data>
```

I am still trying to figure this computer programming stuff out, i have only been coding a few months, so please excuse my bad code and kind of dumb questions, but if anyone knows how to parse the json or xml to html, i will be very grateful.

Comment: you do not need to parse in josn . just use jquery $("body").append(yourXml)

Comment: i have almost 3000 lines of xml file, is it possible to use jquery like $("body").append(yourXml);

Comment: ya you can do that , but it should be html tags xml

Comment: will you please share me any sample code or jsfiddle link, here is my **sample xml code with html tags**,                                                      `<notas>
    <copete>Editorial</copete>
 <titulo>grande</titulo>
 <seccion>Opinion</seccion>
 <cuerpo>
  <p class="rtejustify">
   El 
   <strong>
    <em> Foro Infochannel Tour 2015
    </em>
   </strong> concluyó en días pasados en la hermosa ciudad de Oaxaca, Oaxaca. El escenario para concluir el recorrido no pudo ser mejor. 
  </p>
 </cuerpo>
</notas>`

Comment: check plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nlEzvOeqwyGx7FwlFIEI?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){
  $("body").append('<notas> <copete>Editorial</copete> <titulo>grande</titulo> <seccion>Opinion</seccion> <cuerpo> <p class="rtejustify"> El <strong> <em> Foro Infochannel Tour 2015 </em> </strong> concluyó en días pasados en la hermosa ciudad de Oaxaca, Oaxaca. El escenario para concluir el recorrido no pudo ser mejor. </p> </cuerpo> </notas>')
});
```

check plunkr --

[plnkr.co/edit/nlEzvOeqwyGx7FwlFIEI?p=preview](http://check%20plunkr%20plnkr.co/edit/nlEzvOeqwyGx7FwlFIEI?p=preview)

Comment: 1 more question, by using the function it displays all the content but i need  an individual data from one tag, is it possible to get a specific content by using this function  `$(function(){
  $("body").append('<notas> <copete>Editorial</copete> <titulo>grande</titulo> <seccion>Opinion</seccion> <cuerpo> <p class="rtejustify"> El <strong> <em> Foro Infochannel Tour 2015 </em> </strong> concluyó en días pasados en la hermosa ciudad de Oaxaca, Oaxaca. El escenario para concluir el recorrido no pudo ser mejor. </p> </cuerpo> </notas>')
});`  how to get value of <seccion>?

Comment: Yes it is possible by doing this $(yourxmvariable).find(tagname).text()

Comment: Thanks @ngLover, its very helpful for me. but i my application in need to show the each different tags in different pages using swiper. so i need to use ng-repeat.   By using the above method i will get the value of selected tag, it displays all the selected tag in same page.

Comment: Till i didn't get the accurate answer for my question, @ngLover,